# Updating a Node's FID from file_usage_list

Tags: feeds, services, files

Alright, so this is a bit of an abstract concept; however, I'll give it a shot in accurately depicting the scenario.

I am trying to automate content creation from a production environment down to a development environment in a continuous fashion using Feeds to import content from a REST server created through Services. The content portion is straight forward, and I have no trouble synchronizing and targeting updates via UUID as my guid; however, one problme I realized I will always face is the potential a user has uploaded images or files via the WYSIWYG.

This led me down the path of implementing the File webservice in the Services module, where all managed files in Drupal 7 are tracked by their FID and file object. Using the Drupal 7 API for file.inc, I was able to load and save files via file_save_data or file_save, but this is where I have encountered my issue:

Due to the autoincrementing primary key on the file_managed table, if I am creating a FID that already exists in the development environment, yet the file is not the same file path and is not an updated image, I can only grab the nodeID for which file references this FID through file_usage_list() with file_load(fid); however, there is no simple way to loop through the node_load() object based on that nodeID to find which array in the node contains the FID key matching the appropriate value? Or am I approaching this completely wrong and overthinking it?

If I just copy the file to the base directory, will Drupal handle the file object management on the Feeds import when it encounters the WYSIWYG html?

I should mention the thought process behind this is:

1. Check if the FID was in use
2. Compare the Target URI's to determine if it is a file update
3. If the FID's are not the same file and there is a conflict in the FID's from one environment mapping to different targets in the other, then grab the referenced node for the conflict, update its FID reference using file_save() or file_save_upload() and node_save(), and then proceed with the original creation of the imported file in the file_managed database table

Comment: Is there a reason that the media module's wysiwyg file usage functionality doesn't solve your problem?